# Disable CSS file Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new on Wordpress and I want to disable a CSS file called `col_12.css` from my header (header.php).

How can I do that?

I've tried this:

```
function dequeue_my_css(
    wp_dequeue_style('col_12');
    wp_deregister_style('col_12');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_my_css');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have access to source code, why don't you just remove that include in your functions.php/header.php ?

Comment: try putting it in your functions.php file of your theme

Comment: @Vucko if that css file was included through an 3rd party plugin it would not be wise to just remove from the source code. next time he updates his plugin the change will be undone.

Comment: @Christophe yes, that makes sense. However, the OP didn't say that it's a 3rd party plugin style and I doubt if it was it'd be calles _"col_12"_ .